# Scrolling using javascript not working fast in Ipad

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I execute my operation in scroll function, as bleow

```
    Query(window).scroll(function(){
      jQuery('.ScrollToTop').show();

         // my operation.        
    });
```

In my web page it working fast for my operation.
but it not responding in my Ipad ms fast as web. I tried diffrent coding methods..but no result as web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer following URL Learn more about that. you will get answer for your problem.
[Click Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Comment: What about jquerymobile?

Comment: iOS devices may freeze DOM manipulation during scrolls, which means that it is not possible to change something when the user scrolls. However, the jQuery team are working on a solution for this.